# how to get if value not in oracle group by

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have a table named statustimeline which has structure as

```
id | applicationid | status | createdon
---+---------------+--------+----------
11 |1              |4       |     
---+---------------+--------+----------
10 |1              |3       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
9  |1              |2       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
8  |1              |1       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
7  |2              |3       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
6  |2              |2       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
5  |2              |1       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
4  |3              |5       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
3  |3              |3       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
2  |3              |2       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
1  |3              |1       |
---+---------------+--------+----------
```

if I partition it on application id, there will be three groups.

```
select applicationid,ngstatus, row_number() over (partition by applicationid order by id desc) rownumbr 
from applicationstatustimeline ;
```

i want to select only those applicationid whose group never had status=4 (applicationid = 2 and applicationid = 3 in this case)

is there any function?

Comment: Do you want to return all the matching records, or just the `applicationid` values?

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple `minus` set operator?

```
SQL> with statustimeline (id, applicationid, status) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 11, 1, 4 from dual union all
  4     select 10, 1, 3 from dual union all
  5     select  9, 1, 2 from dual union all
  6     select  8, 1, 1 from dual union all
  7     select  7, 2, 3 from dual union all
  8     select  6, 2, 2 from dual union all
  9     select  5, 2, 1 from dual union all
 10     select  4, 3, 5 from dual union all
 11     select  3, 3, 3 from dual union all
 12     select  2, 3, 2 from dual union all
 13     select  1, 3, 1 from dual
 14    )
 15  -- query you need
 16  select applicationid
 17    from statustimeline
 18  minus
 19  select applicationid
 20    from statustimeline
 21    where status = 4;

APPLICATIONID
-------------
            2
            3

SQL>
```

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to return the full records, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe, @Tim. They said "select only those **applicationid** whose group never had status=4". applicationid, not full records. But maybe I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use analytic functions here, we can use `COUNT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 4 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY applicationid) AS four_cnt
    FROM applicationstatustimeline t
)

SELECT id, applicationid, status, createdon
FROM cte
WHERE four_cnt = 0;
```

In the CTE above, we generate a computed column `four_cnt`, whose value would be identical for every group of `applicationid` records.  That value would be zero assuming `status=4` never occurs, otherwise it would be some value greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yet other option is to use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STATUSTIMELINE S
 WHERE S.STATUS <> 4
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
          FROM STATUSTIMELINE S4
         WHERE S4.STATUS = 4
           AND S.APPLICATIONID = S4.APPLICATIONID
    );
```

Yet another option is to use the `NOT IN` as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM STATUSTIMELINE S
 WHERE S.STATUS <> 4
   AND S.APPLICATIONID NOT IN (
        SELECT S4.APPLICATIONID
          FROM STATUSTIMELINE S4
         WHERE S4.STATUS = 4
    )
```